# MongoDB $bitsAllClear with BinData - how it works?

Tags: mongodb, binary, bitmask

Does anyone knows how the mongodb **$bitsAllClear** works?

I ready the document from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/bitsAllClear/ i am trying to understand how can i create a BinData from a **bitmask**

For example the documentation says:

```
(the binary representation of BinData(0, "ID==") is 00010100.
```

How can i transform the 00010100 to binary to insert in the document? Is there any online converted to try?

Answer (score 1):

> (the binary representation of BinData(0, "ID==") is 00010100.

This example looks incorrect to me. `BinData` takes a base64 encoded string as its second argument, and the base64 encoding of `00010100` is `FA==`. Other examples on that same page look correct, so I suspect it's a typo.

In node, you can do the conversion from a binary string to base64 like so:

```
const hexString = parseInt('00010100', 2).toString(16);
Buffer.from(hexString, 'hex').toString("base64") // FA==
```

Online tool to test out encodings here -> https://cryptii.com/pipes/binary-to-base64